# How do you load specific HTML pages depending on the device detected?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

I know how to make a site semi-responsive using CSS, but that's a lotta work IMO. I'd rather create different pages to see. Is there a way to load different pages dependent on what device is detected in javascript? 
There is this:
http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/
But I'm having to trouble w/ it.

Comment: In the long run, having a bunch of entirely separate pages seems like much more work than creating one responsive layout. What specific issues are you having with mobile-detect?

Comment: I agree with matt, if you have to change something, you have to do it twice, and responsive layout is quite easy with flex, for example.

Comment: More work to create templates for each device than it is to create a responsive template for all devices.  Also if you do your device checking client side and then change template, your page load times ain't gonna be that good

Comment: You should always go responsive, mobile first today. If you want less work try a framework like Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/). Doing individual pages will a lot more work in the end.

Comment: Never use device detection, not least of which because it doesn't work very well at all. Make you site responsive properly using CSS and forget about writing device specific pages

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to load specific pages depend on screen sizes / device, you could compare in javascript

`if ( window.innerWidth < 425 ){// load ajax mobile version}`;

I understand that maybe you think it's faster to make 2 different pages for desktop and mobile version but here it's not best solution. In future when you will have 10 pages, it will be mess. Also it's not that hard to make responsive version. Trust me!

Use this for your responsive instead!

```
@media (screen and max-width: 767px){
   .hero {...}
   .header {...}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Well the issue I'm having is whenever I do a media query, it doesn't work for mobile. Unless my sizing choices are just not right? What would you use for the sizes for tablet, mobile, and desktop, and maybe TV but I doubt anyone uses a TV to search for stuff. NGL.

Comment: There is specific size standards for devices. You can open Chrome Dev Tools (F12 or CMD+CTR+I) and click on top left side phone icon. Then you can choose dimensions on top of your page.

But so you know: - up to 767px all stands for phone devices. - up to 991px for tablets. - up to 1024px small laptops. - up to 1440px normal laptops.

Smallest dimensions I do responsive is 320px (iphone SE) and biggest 2560px (4K screens)